# capture network resource requests on casper.click()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

with **casper.on("resource.requested")**, we can capture the resource requests and perform checks for evaluation.

On page load, we are pushing all the network requests URL in an array and then traverse the array to find the number of calls to GOOGLE Analytics (i.e. _utm.gif).

```
// google analytics calls testing
casper.test.begin('Test Container Tags', function suite(test) {

    casper.start("http://www.viget.com/", function() {

    });

    var urls = [],
        links = [];

    casper.on('resource.requested', function(requestData, resource) {
        urls.push(decodeURI(requestData.url));
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        var index = -1;
        var found = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) 
        {
            index = urls[i].indexOf('__utm.gif');
            if (index > -1)
                found = found+1;
        }
        casper.echo('found' + found);
        test.assert(found > 0, 'Page Load Test Complete');
    });

    //Emit "resource.requested" to capture the network request on link click
    casper.then(function(self) {
        var utils = require('utils');
        var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
        casper.click(x("//a[data-type]"));
        casper.emit('resource.requested');
    });

    casper.run(function() { 
        test.done();
    });
});
```

But, now the next Ask is to verify the network resource requests on hyperlinks click event. Tried to make that work with **casper.emit("resource.requested")** but no success.

Already spent one complete day to find the workaround for the same. ANY feedback would be appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a casper.waitForResource() after the click and do your validation there.

```
casper.test.begin('Test Container Tags', function suite(test) {

casper.start("http://www.viget.com/", function() {

});

var urls = [],
    links = [];

casper.on('resource.requested', function(requestData, resource) {
    urls.push(decodeURI(requestData.url));
});

casper.then(function() {
    var index = -1;
    var found = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) 
    {
        index = urls[i].indexOf('__utm.gif');
        if (index > -1)
            found = found+1;
    }
    casper.echo('found' + found);
    test.assert(found > 0, 'Page Load Test Complete');
});

//Emit "resource.requested" to capture the network request on link click
casper.then(function(self) {
    var utils = require('utils');
    var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
    casper.click(x("//a[data-type]"));

});

casper.waitForResource(function testResource(resource) {
    console.log('----->' + resource.url);
});

casper.run(function() { 
    test.done();
});
```

});